# Decomposing a product set into orbits

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

The symmetric group S3 operates on two sets U and V of order 3.

Decompose the product set $U × V$ into orbits for the “diagonal action” $g(u,v) = (gu,gv)$ when

$(a)$ The operations on U and V are transitive

$ (b) $ The operation on U is transitive and the orbits for the operation on V are {v1} and {v2,v3}.

I don't really have any idea how to do this. Any help that could be given would be appreciated.

Comment: Idea: figure out how $S_3$ acts on $U$ and $V$, then write down the elements of $U\times V$ and see how it acts on *those* elements. See what happens. Don't be scared to write stuff down and do work, even if you don't know where it will lead you.

Comment: Do you know the basic definitions?  Take U= {a, b, c} and V= {x, y, z}.  So $U\times V= \{(a, x), (b, x), (c, x), (a, y), (b, y), (c, y), (a, z), (b, z), (c, z)\}$. Do you kow what " Do you know what "transitive" means?  Do you know  what "transitive" means?  Do you know what "orbits" are?

Comment: This is probably not the most efficient: a transitive action on a three-element set means any stabilizer has order two.  The stabilizer of $(u,v)$ is the intersections of the stabilizers of $u$ and $v$, so there are two cases depending on whether the stabilizers are the same.  If they are the same, each orbit of $U\times V$ is order three, and otherwise order six.  To fully understand it, you could use the fact that all the order-two subgroups of $S_3$ are conjugate, and that the stabilizers of different elements of a transitive set exhaust the conjugate subgroups.

Comment: @user247327 We put dollar signs around $\LaTeX$ markup.

Comment: yeh, I know what orbits are and what transitive is, and the product set, I'm just unfamiliar with decomposing into orbits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at (a). The elements of the symmetric group $S_3$ are

- The identity $e=()$,
- The transpositions $(12)$, $(23)$ and $(31)$,
- The $3$-cycles $(123)$, $(132)$.

You should already know how $S_3$ acts on $\{1,2,3\}$ transitively: it's the standard action. (Every permutation is just a function you apply to this set.)

So then, the elements of $U\times V$ are the ordered pairs

$$ \begin{array}{ccc} (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) \\ (2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) \\ (3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) \end{array} $$

The "diagonal" action is when we apply a permutation to both components simultaneously. So for example if $\pi=(123)$ then $\pi\cdot(1,2)=(\pi(1),\pi(2))=(2,3)$.

Start with $(1,1)$. Apply different permutations to it. Experiment! Test things out! Now, after some exploration, can you form a hypothesis as to what the orbit is? (The range of ordered pairs that can be gotten to from $(1,1)$ by applying a permutation to it.) Now *prove* it's an orbit.

Next, pick an ordered pair not in the orbit you already found. Can you take it from there?

---

For part (b) we'll want to understand how $S_3$ acts on $V=\{\circ,\oplus,\ominus\}$:

- The element $\circ$ is fixed. That is, $\pi\cdot\circ=\circ$ for all $\pi$.
- $e,(123),(132)$ fix both of $\oplus$ and $\ominus$, whereas $(12),(23),(31)$ all swap $\oplus\leftrightarrow\ominus$.

Now write down the elements of $U\times V$ again and go spelunking.

Comment: Am i right in saying that the orbit of $(1,1)$ would be ${(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}$

Comment: @Brum Yep! Now what about, say, $(1,2)$?

Comment: That orbit would be the rest of the ordered pairs?

Comment: @Brum Correct! Given any "diagonal" pair $(x,x)$, we have $\pi\cdot(x,x)=(\pi(x),\pi(x))$ is *also* diagonal. Given any two $x,y$, there is some $\pi$ with $\pi(x)=y$, so any two diagonal pairs $(x,x)$ and $(y,y)$ are in the same orbit. Then for pairs $(i,j)$ with $i\ne j$, if $k$ is the element of $\{1,2,3\}$ that isn't $i$ or $j$, we can consider the permutation $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ i & j & k \end{pmatrix} $$ (in two-line notation), in which case $\pi\cdot(1,2)=(i,j)$, so all of the off-diagonal pairs are in a single orbit.

Comment: So now we have the decomposition into orbits right?

Comment: For part (a), yes. I updated my answer for how to interpret the problem in part (b).

Comment: okay, thank you very much, I will give that a go now

Comment: In part (b), how did you know that elements of $S_3$ act on these three symbols in the way you pointed out?

Comment: @Cary An action of $S_3$ on a one-element set must be trivial, and the only transitive action $S_3\to S_2$ on a two-element set is the one in which odd permutations swap the two things and even permutations do nothing.

Comment: @arctic tern how can $s_3$ act on a one or two element set when by def it acts on 3 element sets?

Comment: @arctic tern In the answer to part B, how can (123) fix anything if it cycles all elements? I guess I don't understand the question in B, how can the operation of s3 not act transitively on V?

Comment: @user35687 Remember a group action of $S_3$ on $V$ is a group homomorphism $S_3\to{\rm Perm}(V)$. So an element of $S_3$ can, in principle, behave differently when applied to $V$ versus when applied to $\{1,2,3\}$. Indeed, if $\sigma$ is the permutation of $V$ that switches the elements in the two-element orbit, then the map $S_3\to{\rm Perm}(V)$ sends a permutation $\pi$ to the identity function ${\rm id}_V$ if $\pi$ is even and to the transposition $\sigma$ if $\pi$ is odd; this is a homomorphism and therefore defines a group action.

Answer (score 0):

replaced $u_1$, $u_2$, $u_3$ by 1, 2, 3

```
()U         1      2      3
(1 2)U      2      1      3
(2 3)U      1      3      2
(3 1)U      3      2      1
(1 2 3)U    2      3      1
(1 3 2)U    3      1      2
           ↓      ↓      ↓
       ｛1,2,3｝｛1,2,3｝｛1,2,3｝
```

on $U$ are transitive

so $S_3$ is divided into 1 piece, $S_3$ itself

for (a), $U×V$ is divided by whole $S_3$, and is still $U×V$

and for (b), orbits on $V$ are {1}, {2, 3}

```
()V         **1**      2      3
(1 2)V        2        1      3
(2 3)V      **1**      3      2
(3 1)V        3        2      1
(1 2 3)V      2        3      1
(1 3 2)V      3        1      2
```

so {(), (2 3)} is a part of separation, so do {(1 2), (1 3 2)}, {(3 1) (1 2 3)}

replaced $(u_i, v_j)$ by $(i, j)$

```
()(U×V)      (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3)
             (2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3)
             (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3)

(2 3)(U×V)   (1, 1) (1, 3) (1, 2)
             (3, 1) (3, 3) (3, 2)
             (2, 1) (2, 3) (2, 2)

(1 2)(U×V)   (2, 2) (2, 1) (2, 3)
             (1, 2) (1, 1) (1, 3)
             (3, 2) (3, 1) (3, 3)

(1 3 2)(U×V) (3, 3) (3, 1) (3, 2)
             (1, 3) (1, 1) (1, 2)
             (2, 3) (2, 1) (2, 2)

(3 1)(U×V)   (3, 3) (3, 2) (3, 1)
             (2, 3) (2, 2) (2, 1)
             (1, 3) (1, 2) (1, 1)

(1 2 3)(U×V) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 1)
             (3, 2) (3, 3) (3, 1)
             (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 1)
```

as we see, in each separation, (1, 1) is fixed, (1, 2), (1, 3) are exchanged each other, and so on

so here may be the answer of (b)

{($u_1$, $v_1$)},

{($u_1$, $v_2$), ($u_1$, $v_3$)},

{($u_2$, $v_1$), ($u_3$, $v_1$)},

{($u_2$, $v_2$), ($u_3$, $v_3$)},

{($u_2$, $v_3$), ($u_3$, $v_2$)}